# i want to apperar icon ontap in inside container

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to make my child as invisible at initial stage. Then child need to show icon onTap. In my code _yes is the child where i need to make my changes.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      _ansContainer = _ansContainer == Colors.grey ? Colors.green : Colors.grey;
      _done = _done == Colors.transparent ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent;
      
    });
  },
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: _ansContainer),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    ), //decoration
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Answer 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16), //textStyle
        ), //text
        Container(
          height: 26,
          width: 26,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: _done,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            border: Border.all(color: _ansContainer),
          ), //boxdecoration
          child: Icon(_yes),
        ), //container
      ], //widget
    ), //row
  ),
), //container
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a bool variable and setstate on onTap function.
and check in the row widget to weather to display it or not.

```
final bool visible = false;
InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    visible != visible;
                    _ansContainer = _ansContainer == Colors.grey ? Colors.green : Colors.grey;
                    _done = _done == Colors.transparent ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent;
                    
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: _ansContainer),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ), //decoration
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Answer 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16), //textStyle
                      ), //text
                      //check statement here
                      (visible == true)?Container(
                        height: 26,
                        width: 26,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: _done,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          border: Border.all(color: _ansContainer),
                        ), //boxdecoration
                        child: Icon(_yes),
                      ):SizedBox(), //container
                    ], //widget
                  ), //row
                ),
              ), //container
```